# trim() on an empty EditText returns false android

Tags: android, android-edittext

i have the following

```
String newWord = (String) addNewWordEdTxt.getText().toString();
Log.d(TAG_WORD, "A:"+ String.valueOf(newWord.trim() == "" ));
Log.d(TAG_WORD, "B:" + String.valueOf( TextUtils.isEmpty(addNewWordEdTxt.getText().toString().trim() )));
```

anyone know why A is false and B is true for an empty EditText

thanks

Comment: i thinks java compare with string to any string use .equals() method not used == that why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> anyone know why A is false and B is true for an empty EditText

Because in **A** case, you are comparing references and not quality so you have to do it like that:

```
Log.d(TAG_WORD, "A:"+ String.valueOf(newWord.trim().equals("")));
```

**Note:** There is one golden rule: If you want to compare `Strings`, always use `equals()` method!

Here is nice explanation:

- [`How do I compare strings in Java?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

i thinks java  a string compare with any string use .equals() method not used ==

that's like

```
String.valueOf(newWord.trim().equals(""));
```